# passing variables by ajax to php page

Tags: php, ajax

i've a problem when passwing values with ajax i have a plus and minus buttons and input when i use input it works well to pass the value but with plus or minus it not working it works only on one item and the other items take the same value of the first

```
 <button class="entry number-minus" data-id="<?=$cartRowID?> " type="button">&nbsp;</button>
 <input type="hidden" name="itemSizesList" value="<?=$itemSizeList?>" />
 <input id="itemid" type="hidden" name="submittedForm" value="<?=$cartItemdID?>_<?=$cartListCounter?>" />
 <input type="hidden" name="itemID" value="<?=encrypt_decrypt("encrypt",$cartItemdID)?>" />
 <input type="hidden" name="cartRowID" value="<?=encrypt_decrypt("encrypt",$cartRowID)?>" />
 <input class="entry number " name="newQty" data-id="<?=$cartRowID?>" value="<?=$cartItemQty?>" style="margin-top: 1px; width:44px"/>
 <button class="entry number-plus" data-id="<?=$cartRowID?>" type="button">&nbsp;</button>
 <input type="submit" class="button style-17" value="Remove" name="delete" />
 <input type="submit" class="button style-15" value="Update cart" name="update" />
```

ajax code:

```
// WHEN - IS CLICKED
 $(document).on('click', '.number-minus', function(){
            var rowid = $(this).data("id");
            var qty = $('.number').val();
            // edit_data(eachItemSize, "eachItemSize");

            $.ajax({
                url:"update.php?rowid="+rowid+"qty="+qty,
                method:"POST",
                data:{rowid:rowid , qty:qty},
                dataType:"text",
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });

        // WHEN + IS CLICKED
        $(document).on('click', '.number-plus', function(){
            var rowid = $(this).data("id");
            var qty = $('.number').val();
            // edit_data(eachItemSize, "eachItemSize");

            $.ajax({
                url:"update.php?rowid="+rowid+"qty="+qty,
                method:"POST",
                data:{rowid:rowid , qty:qty},
                dataType:"text",
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: If you want us to understand your issue, it helps if you use some punctuation when explaining it to us. Right now, it's just one single sentence which makes it really hard to read. It also helps if you give us some proper examples of the issue.

Comment: i have a cart page contain the cart items if the user want to change the quantity ha can change it by plus or minus or write the number i have a problem when he click on plus or minus if he has 3 items he can only change the first item but the second and third can not it takes the same value of the first item but when he writes the quantity it works well

Comment: Please read my comment again. Specifically the part about _punctuation_. Then you should edit your actual question. Posting one equally as long (if not longer) comment doesn't really help. When asking a question, you should make sure that you write it as proper as possible.

Comment: `data-id="<?=$cartRowID?> "`. Get rid of that space.

Comment: @delboy1978uk not the main issue

Comment: yeah but it aint going to help if it screws your id up is it?

Comment: @delboy1978uk yes thank u :) but the main problem still not solved :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are grabbing values by class, not by ID!

Therefore when you call `var qty = $('.number').val();`, you are probably getting the value of the first item, assuming that this is one row and that there are other rows with these fields too.

Update: okay, you have multiple forms. So, probably the easiest way to get the correct field of class `.number` using jQuery is probably using `.parent()` and `.find()`:

```
var qty = $(this).parent().find('.number').val();
```

This assumes that `.parent()` will return the form element, and `.find()` checks only within that form.

Comment: so change class to id?!

Comment: Hmm, looking at it, you only have one row with that class, so possibly not. I still recommend you use ID's for that sort of thing though

Comment: Is this one row? Do you have this stuff multiple times on the page?

Comment: i used ID but still have the same problem

Comment: can you paste the full html?

Comment: yes but with different item i got all these items from database

Comment: yes it is in form    <form method="post" action="" id="<?=encrypt_decrypt("encrypt",$cartItemdID)?>_<?=$cartListCounter?>">

Comment: Glad I could help amigo, have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

HTML part:

I entered static value in data-id=12 for minus button & value=6 for class number. And i m getting alert values when minus button entered. If this is not solution then tell me what exactly it breaking..

```
<button class="entry number-minus" data-id="12" type="button">-</button>
 <input type="hidden" name="itemSizesList" value="" />
 <input id="itemid" type="hidden" name="submittedForm" value="" />
 <input type="hidden" name="itemID" value="" />
 <input type="hidden" name="cartRowID" value="" />
 <input class="entry number " name="newQty" data-id="" value="6" style="margin-top: 1px; width:44px"/>
 <button class="entry number-plus" data-id="" type="button">+</button>
 <input type="submit" class="button style-17" value="Remove" name="delete" />
 <input type="submit" class="button style-15" value="Update cart" name="update" />
```

Script part:

```
$(document).on('click', '.number-minus', function(){

            var rowid = $(this).data("id");
            var qty = $('.number').val();
            // edit_data(eachItemSize, "eachItemSize");
            alert(rowid);
            alert(qty);
            $.ajax({
                url:"update.php?rowid="+rowid+"qty="+qty,
                method:"POST",
                data:{rowid:rowid , qty:qty},
                dataType:"text",
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: no it is not the solution i get the values but only on one item not all the item other items take the same value of the first

Comment: instead of class use id to get value.